# Angular ui-router subview issues

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've been working with Angular for a year or 2 now, but this is my first project using ui-router.  I'm running into a few issues with views and sub-views.  The app is a standard left-side menu bar, with the views on the right changing depending on what's clicked in the menu bar.

On index.html

```
<body>
    <div ui-view></div>
</body>
```

In the config.js file, which defines the routes

```
 .state("dashboard", {
        url: "/dashboard",
        templateUrl: "components/dashboard/dashboard.html",
        data: {
            pageTitle: "Dashboard",
            requiresLogin: false
        }
    })

    .state("dashboard.welcome", {
        url: "/welcome",
        templateUrl: "components/welcome/welcome.html",
        data: {
            pageTitle: "Welcome",
            requiresLogin: false
        }
    })
```

In the dashboard.html file

```
 <div class="dashboard">
    <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
       <div ui-view>
```

The `/dashboard` path loads correctly, and will load the left-side navigation bar with a blank right side.  But changing the state to `dashboard.welcome` (`/welcome`) will not load the welcome.html template.

Comment: are you sure you are changing URL to `/dashboard/welcome`?

Comment: Shouldn't it just be "/welcome" since that's the mapping in the state for "dashboard.welcome"

Comment: no..it becomes combination of parent(`/dashboard`) + child(`/welcome`)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever working with `ui-router` you need to understand that the concept of states is different from routes. When you define a sub-state, its defined relative to its parent state. In your scenario `dashboard.welcome` is defined as a child state of `dashboard`. The routes to substate is relative to the parent and is `{parent url}/{child url}`. Hence you should use either of the below 2 to route to that state:

**Using $state.go change the state by specifying state name**

```
$state.go('dashboard.welcome');
```

**Using $location.path change the route by specifying url**

```
$location.path('/dashboard/welcome');
```

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#url-routing-for-nested-states.  I recomend the nested url but if you need use absolute url must prefix your url string with a special symbol '^'. that is url: '^/welcome'

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want links to `/welcome` to be for state `dashboard.welcome`.  Here is a plunker showing how this can be done.  I show two sets of dashboard and welcome states.  The first set of states (dashboard & welcome) shows that `/dashboard/welcome` will bring you to the `dashboard.welcome` state.

The second set (dashboard2 & welcome2) shows that `/welcome` will go to state `dashboard2.welcome2`.  I believe this is what you were looking for.

If you hover over the links you can see where they will take you.

https://plnkr.co/edit/AVKPFa?p=info

Answer (score 1):

Nested routes in ui-router get nested urls. I would however recommend using named-views for this kind of structure. You can find more info about it here:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views

The gist of it is: you can specify a named component (ui-view) for your left menu navigation and another one for content, which gives you much more control down the line, because named components can be overwritten in child states or they can keep the default template, depending on your needs.

Example:

```
.state('root', {
            url: '',
            abstract: true,
            views: {
                'header': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/partials/header.html',
                    controller: 'headerCtrl'
                },
                'logo': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/partials/logoView.html'
                },
                'footer':{
                    templateUrl: 'templates/partials/footer.html',
                    controller: 'footerCtrl'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('root.login', {
            url: '/login',
            views: {
                'header@': {
                    template: ''
                },
                'container@': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
                    controller: 'loginController'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('root.report', {
            url: '/report',
            views: {
                'container@': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/eu_dashboard.html',
                    controller: 'reportController'
                }
            }
    })
```

And in your index.html:

```
<div ui-view="logo"></div>
<div ui-view="header"></div>
<div id="mainView" ui-view="container"></div>
<div ui-view="footer"></div>
```

Comment: Well remembered. If there is a native resource, it is almost always the best option. In this particular case, it is easier to achieve the goal.

Helped me, thank you!